# Request.security() helps to focus on a specific timeframe. How to do it alternatively to prevent 'overuse'? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have boolean variables containing a huge amount of `open`s and `close`s and `high`s and `low`s (and they may still counting). I could apply a `request.security()` enclosure for each of them (skipping the security attribute, of course) but;

Is there a way to specify the timeframe for the whole boolean expression? E.g. (sort of)

```
SomethingHappened = (high > close) and (low < high) <= always in 1-min timeframe
```

instead of

```
SomethingHappened = request.security("","1",high) > request.security("","1",close) and
                    request.security("","1",low) < request.security("","1",high)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any variable or function (with some exceptions) to `request.security()`, not just built-ins. You can pass your `SomethingHappened` variable directly to the `request.security()` and it will return you the result of the calculation from the 1m timeframe:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
SomethingHappened = (high > close) and (low < high)// <= always in 1-min timeframe
s1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", SomethingHappened)
plot(s1 ? 1 : 0)
```

Note that while requesting data from lower timeframes, some data is inevitably lost (because one bar of the main timeframe can only have one value, while the `request.security()` provides several for each bar). If your main chart timeframe is `10`, and you request data from `1`, only one in each 10 minutes will be represented on the main chart.

Comment: O-oo, this error message happened. Any idea? "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function."

To the line of: s1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", SomethingHappened)

Comment: Mutable variables (variables that are first defined and then changed via `:=` or similar operators) cannot be used inside `request.security()`. This is because things that you pass to the function are separately calculated on the symbol/timeframe you specify, so they need to be "extracted". You can wrap them in a custom function and pass the function to security instead (see here, it's v3 code but the core concept is the same: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#resolving-a-problem-with-a-mutable-variable-in-a-security-expression)

Comment: Wow. The problem is, it's mutable with a reason. I tried to make a workaround by covering the mutable variable with a non-mutable one by "Variable = OtherVariable and MutableVariable" but it's still mutable according to the error message. :/ 

Practically, the 'Variable' in the request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", Variable) function is definitely not mutable. At least it was defined by =, not :=

Is there any workaround that works?

Comment: It's hard to do this in comments, please create a new issue, describe the problem and attach the code that reproduces the issue, and I (or somebody else who browses this tag) will take a look. But a variable that includes another mutable variable in its calculation becomes mutable too.

Comment: Hello, would you please look at my question, linked? I simplified the code sample for making it easy-readable. I'm stuck here. :( Thank you very much. shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175465/failed-to-avoid-mutable-variable-error-message-on-request-security-what-did